# How to optimally read first and last XML node with a matching node attribute

Tags: java, xml

I'm stuck with an optimally solution on this problem, so it would be very nice if you could give me a little hint on this one.
Basically, I'm having an XML file with the following nodes:

```
<Cell type="typeA" step="0" name="name1">expression</Cell>
<Cell type="typeA" step="1" name="name1">expression</Cell>
...
<Cell type="typeA" step="5" name="name1">expression</Cell>
...
<Cell type="typeA" step="0" name="name2">expression</Cell>
<Cell type="typeA" step="1" name="name2">expression</Cell>
...
<Cell type="typeB" step="0" name="name3">expression</Cell>
...
<Cell type="typeB" step="4" name="name3">expression</Cell>
```

There are only two types available: typeA and typeB which I'm filtering at the beginning, the name can be any string, same applies to the content of the node.

I would like to create a new object (let's call it Cell) in which I would like to have the name of the object, the start and end step and the expression.

Which is the most optimal way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear how many `Cell` objects you want from that input, what would constitute a single `Cell`, which value is the `start`, which the `end` step? Consider to show the resulting `Cell` objects for the input you have posted. As for optimal way, it is not clear which criteria you want to apply, which technology (XSLT, XPath, XQuery, serialization).

Comment: Based on the provided example, there would be 3 cell objects: one with the `startStep=0` and `endStep=5`, one with `startStep=0`, `endStep=1`, and the other one with `startStep=0`, `endStep=4`. As for the technology, XPath would be ok

Answer (score 0):

XSLT grouping might help e.g. with XSLT 3

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    expand-text="yes"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Cells">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="Cell" composite="yes" group-by="@type, @name">
              <Cell name="{@name}" start-step="{@step}" end-step="{current-group()[last()]/@step}">{.}</Cell>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives

```
<Cells>
   <Cell name="name1" start-step="0" end-step="5">expression</Cell>
   <Cell name="name2" start-step="0" end-step="1">expression</Cell>
   <Cell name="name3" start-step="0" end-step="4">expression</Cell>
</Cells>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXy

On the Java platform, XSLT 3 is supported by Saxon 10 or 9.8 or 9.9 HE, available on Maven and Sourceforge.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution, but I'm afraid I can not use XSLT in this case. Is there any other way to do this (maybe parsing the XML nodes or using XPath)? Thanks!

Comment: @LăpădatRăzvan, well both XPath and XSLT use an underlying XML parser and work with nodes; I see it as a grouping problem for which pure XPath is not really meant, for that you can use XQuery or XSLT, unless you want to try to do it with XPath 3.1 maps instead of plain grouping. As for other solutions, let's see what other people suggest, Java 8 and later have grouping for streams so I guess that would also be a way to approach it.